# I need to create Event Grid Topic based on existing Event Grid Topic

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I have one existing Event Grid Topic and it has lot of subscription to different azure functions. Now I have create another Event Grid Topic with all those those event subscription. How i can import or copy those subscription Event Grid Topic

When I export template it doesn't contain event subscriptions

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: Guys I found , I can't use this using azure portal, I will tray Plumi